# Can I change device DPI programmatically?

Tags: android

I was wondering if I can change device which decides which layout it should choose or which graphic it should choose/scale. This change should only affect my application of course. Can I set somehow device DPI?

The reason why I'm doing that is this phone: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p1000_galaxy_tab-3370.php it has very bad DPI od 240DPI while it's only 170PPI and should be recognized as 160DPI device.
I have quite big graphic for layout-large which looks great on mdpi, but on hdpi they doesn't fit, they are just to big.

Maybe you have another solution than changing device DPI?

Comment: it is impossible to change device dpi, you can set only dpi for application based on device!

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. You could as well ask how to programmatically change your monitor's diameter. DPI is a hardware feature. There are as many pixels in an inch as the hardware manufacturer puts in there (that's assuming you mean DPI = PPI).

Comment: DPI is not hardware value, and I'm not assuming DPI=PPI. DPI is used to decribe screen which resources should we use etc, while PPI is real screen density.

Comment: It is a hardware feature, and if you're talking about DPI of a smartphone screen, you probably mean PPI. Quoting from Wikipedia: "A less misleading term, therefore, is pixels per inch. Video displays are almost universally rated in dot pitch, which refers to the spacing between the sub-pixel red, green and blue dots which make up the pixels themselves." Since (sub)pixels are physical entities of any LCD, the DPI value is a hardware constant for such screens. What Android *does* allow you, however, is to provide pre-rendered or pre-scaled resources for *different* screen densities upfront.

Comment: PS: See Hassy31's answer, that's what you should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should create your application
to support with multiple screens.take a look at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

and hope these links helps you

[Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

[Working with Multiple Android Screens](http://www.slideshare.net/motodev/ui-multiplescreens)

Comment: I'm doing it right, but when I'm using layout-large I expect to have more space like 600dp. But this phone in portait mode has 800px/1.5hdpi=400dp.

Comment: Here they say that: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp which is not true for that device. And at the bottom in the table there is information that devices 600x1024 in hdpi should choose normal qualifier. So this device is bugggy?

Comment: I had the same problem.there are few devices in same density with different resolutions.in that case you can select the layout programmatically.but that procedure will make you feel like hell because you have to create lot of layouts for different resolutions.creating layout using relativelayout would be a much better solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't like your answer, but it's not quite answer for my problem ;) However that's probably best i can do...

Comment: I myself find my solution a lot easier to manage numerous devices with one css to display it how it should. http://www.jqui.net/tips-tricks/fixing-the-auto-scale-on-mobile-devices/ cross platform and tested in a few devices with accuratecy

Comment: It is possible to change through build.prop for rooted phones at least.

Comment: I guess it was not possible in 2012, but now filip1299 answer worked on every devices I tested it on. It should by the right answer, as it is so useful for some Samsung devices, where declared density does not match real density

Answer (score 21):

Yes it is possible. 
The following will set the dpi to 240. Although you have to refresh the activity somehow e.g. restart application.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.density = 1.5f;
metrics.densityDpi = 240;
metrics.heightPixels = 1104;
metrics.widthPixels = 1920;
metrics.scaledDensity = 1.5f;
metrics.xdpi = 254.0f;
metrics.ydpi = 254.0f;
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().setTo(metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 take layout from layout-xhdpi if this not there then it will look for large.

Try to support multiples screen resolution for your app based on that [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
you have to Design alternative layouts and drawables for your app

Comment: layouts should be defined by size then by dpi if needed