# Trying to programmatically set DPI for second screen on my Android device

Tags: java, android, adb, dpi, runtime.exec

I have an Android device with 2 displays and I need to set the second display's DPI programmatically. It works with the following command over ADB (and then perform a restart to see the changes) :

```
wm density 160 -d 1
```

but when I try to programmatically run this command (and then restart the device):

```
 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wm density "+Constants.DPI_TO_SET_DEVICE_TO+" -d 1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

nothing seems to happen. Am I doing something wrong here? I've also researched using DisplayMetrics to do this programmatically as well, but that doesn't seem to be able to set a second `display` DPI that I'm aware of. Am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: You can't run ADB commands like that. Try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750629/can-i-change-device-dpi-programmatically

Comment: @Philio I've found that answer myself, but how does that interact with the second display? The flag at the end of this command "-d 1" should point to the second display on the device.